# Symfony 3 : Sending the $options argument values from formType to underFormType

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I've created a tag system in a bundle using a formType (TagsType) which I include in my main formType (See below). 
I'd like to know how I can send the $options argument values from MyFormType to TagsType.

```
//...

use EC\TagBundle\Form\Type\TagsType;

class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {


    $builder        

    //...
        ->add('tags', TagsType::class)
    //...
    ;
    }
}
```

My TagsType

```
//...

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class TagsType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->addModelTransformer( new CollectionToArrayTransformer(), true )
            ->addModelTransformer( new TagsTransformer($this->manager), true )
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefault('attr', [
            'class' => 'tag-input',

        ]);
        $resolver->setDefault('required', false);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        // Il retourne un TextType par défaut.
        return TextType::class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found. Just do this :

```
->add('tags', TagsType::class, ['empty_data' => $options])
```

TagsType.php

```
$options = $options['empty_data'];
```